# Measure distance between two Android phones

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android app development. My doubt is how to measure the distance between to phone connected through internet.
And how to display the two phone as a point on both phone.

Answer (score 2):

**First you need to learn about android programming** but here are some clue for you:

For measure the distance between two phones, You need to know the location of each phone. With android [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) you can get last location from `GPS` or `network` and then you can find distance from difference between two latitude and longitude.

For display position of other phones, you can use google map api in your app.